# Topology over $C^0(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: general-topology, functions

Let $C^0(\mathbb{R})$ be the set of continuous functions $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,

For any continuous function $h > 0$  consider

$B_f(h) = \{ g \in C^0(\mathbb{R}) :  |f(x) - g(x) | < h(x) \forall x \}$

Set $\tau$ the lowest (coarsest) topology over $C^0(\mathbb{R})$ where  the sets $B_f(h)$ are open.

I am trying to figure out if $\tau$ is a Hausdorff Topology or is not. Thanks for any hint.

Comment: What do you mean by "lowest", do you mean coarsest or finest?

Comment: @jowehler I guess coarsest

Comment: I mean coarsest for sure, finest would imply $\tau$ discrete and thus a trivial question. Edit: I changed the word in the original question to avoid ambiguities

Comment: Try to see if you can put a metric on this topology.

Comment: If $f(x)\neq g(x)$ for some $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then you can choose $h$ to be the *constant* function $|g(x)-f(x)|/2$ and $B_f(h)$, $B_g(h)$ are disjoint.